# JQuery ON selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created custom JS function which uses keyboard to work with table rows. In fact, I use up/down keys to select row (preview details) and Enter to simulate double click (edit details).

It is working very well, you can view working example at http://jsfiddle.net/n6hn2/19/
Just Focus on table and try Up/Down/Enter and see Console..

1. Why this doesn't work with selector, like this

   ```
   $('#' + tableid).on('keyup', 'tbody', function(e) {...
   ```

   also tried 'tbody tr' as selector, and `$('#' + tableid + ' tbody tr')` but nothing.
2. When I enter something in input box (`search_article`), and HIT Enter, my function DblClick is triggered. Which is, in fact OK without selector, but I don't want that.

Comment: tbody cannot be focused, that's why keyup event is not fired. See setting attribute tabindex on tbody: http://jsfiddle.net/n6hn2/21/

Comment: sorry, forget to mention you then should bring focus on tbody, not table: http://jsfiddle.net/n6hn2/26/ (or in previous jsfiddle, click on tbody to give it focus) You could wish to remove focused outline style, using e.g: `#tableid :focus {outline:none;}` http://jsfiddle.net/n6hn2/28/

Comment: This is A correct answer. How can I vote and set as Answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `tbody` element is not focusable, you need to set any tabindex attribute on tbody, e.g:

```
tabindex="-1"
```

See complete [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n6hn2/28/) using CSS outline too:

```
#tableid :focus {outline:none;}
```

So then, you can use keyup handler on tbody:

```
$('#' + tableid).on('keyup', 'tbody', function(e) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to add tabindex="0" add your class or id

like this :

```
 <table id="tableid" tabindex="0">
```

and

```
$("#tableid").on('keyup', function(){
    console.log("2");
});
```

test it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/n6hn2/25/

Comment: Already have that in my example. Bu tyou were close, it is problem with tabindex

Answer (score 0):

I've forked the code and this fiddle seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/5mxS2/

The biggest difference is that the `on` now attaches to the `input` like this:

```
$('#' + tableid + ' input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    alert('up');
});
```

Comment: Sorry I just checked your example again. This is not what I want. I want to keep my functions for up/down/enter, but for TBODY, not for TABLE. For other part thead/input or else I'll wrote another function. thanks anyway